# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while reading from a Python NamedPipe

Tags: python, named-pipes, psexec

I've a NamedPipe Server written in Powershell and a NamedPipe Client written in Python. The following is my NamedPipe Client:

```
def namedpipeClient():
    print "Inside NamedPipeClient"
    time.sleep(2)
    f = open(r'\\x.x.x.x\pipe\testpipe', 'r+b', 0)
    i = 1
    n = struct.unpack('I', f.read(4))[0]    # Read str length
    s = f.read(n)                           # Read str
    f.seek(0)                               # Important!!!
    f.close()
    print 'Read:', s
    if (s is None):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I'm starting the NamedPipeServer in C# in one machine, and in another machine I'll be running the NamedPipeClient via a batch file. The following is my batch file runTest.bat

```
c:
cd \Python27
.\python D:\LoadTesting\SikuliNPClient.py
```

So running this way executes everything without any issues.

Now if I try to execute the same batch file in the same machine but remotely from the machine where I'm starting the NamedPipeServer via a psexec, `psexec \\$remoteMachine -i 0 -d Powershell D:\LoadTesting\runTest.bat` the batch file gets executed, but at the `f = open(r'\\x.x.x.x\pipe\testpipe', 'r+b', 0)` statement, it throws the following error.

```
Inside NamedPipeClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LoadTesting\SikuliNPClient.py", line 40, in <module>
    namedpipeClient()
  File "D:\LoadTesting\SikuliNPClient.py", line 9, in namedpipeClient
    f = open(r'\\192.168.173.231\pipe\testpipe', 'r+b', 0)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\x.x.x.x\\pipe\\testpipe'
```

I'm logged in two machines as same users only which have admin privileges as well.
Kindly help me figure out the issue I've.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and removing `+` from mode worked like a charm. In your case, instead of `r+b` try `rb`.
Hope it helps.